# sjplot: How to change the label of interaction term in an interaction back and white graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

In the following graph, I try to manually change the wording "type_vote". I struggle a lot with this.

[image]

Find below the code. Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

```
plot_model(m3, type = "int", colors = "bw") +
   labs(title = "", y = "T", x = "X")
```

Comment: Add `shape = 'my new label'` inside `labs`

Comment: Thanks!!! Very helpful. I've been trying very different methods for more than one hour, it was actually quite easy...